# Subsequent acquires on semaphore on the same thread

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I'm trying to use a semaphore to lock a thread for a few seconds before it gives up on trying to acquire the lock and carries on. The problem is, I think the semaphore is not actually locking anything. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
Semaphore lock = new Semaphore(1)
lock.acquire();

//Wait until some other thread releases the lock, or until the timeout
lock.tryAcquire(WAIT_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

//do whatever
```

I think the problem is: trying to acquire twice from the same thread does not prevent the thread from running if it has already acquired the lock. But I'm not sure. Is that what's happening?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Strange way to block your own thread. Are you looking for `Thread.sleep()`?

Answer (score 2):

Explanation of what is happening in your code

1. `lock.acquire();` Acquires a permit from this semaphore, blocking until one is available. Since you just trying to acquire and 1 permit available then it will acquire immediately.
2. `lock.tryAcquire(WAIT_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);` since 1 permit already acquired (from previous line of code), this will never acquire lock until someone release the lock. So it will wait/block until timeout I mean `WAIT_INTERVAL` time elapses. And this method return a `boolean` value `true` if a permit was acquired and `false` if the waiting time elapsed before a permit was acquired. So it will return `false` obviously.